# Javascript : What's wrong with this script?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I've successfully used this calculate script on one of my page, however, when I reused it in the other one. That page keep saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined " I don't understand what's wrong with this script. So could you please help me. Thank you.

```
<script>
function startCalc(){ //automatically calculate total after discount when adding new order
  interval = setInterval("calc()",1);
}
function calc(){
 // for calculate each product order
 var price;
 var qty;
 var od_total;
  price = document.myform.od_price.value;
  qty = document.myform.od_qty.value; 
  od_total = (price * 1) * (qty * 1);
  document.myform.od_total.value = od_total.toFixed(2);  
}

function stopCalc(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
</script>
```

I used this script with

```
<input id="od_qty" name="od_qty" type="text" size="8" value="" maxlength="100" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();">
<input id="od_price" type="text" size="4" value="<%=rs.fields.item("cust_price")%>" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();"  >
<input id="od_total"  name="od_total" type="text" size="10" value="" maxlength="100" readonly="true">
```

Comment: i think you are missing name attribute for `od_price` element

Comment: no.. that's not the cause. I've added that name however, the error still exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with the page structure. The fields must be in a form called `myform` to make `document.myform.od_price.value` work. You could change the line to

```
document.getElementById('od_price').value
```

to just select it using the id and not the form name. The same goes fo the second field - `od_qty`.

Comment: thank you very much. But what i don't understand is that this tag were in the form name "myform" already. but why the script couldn't detect it?

Comment: Maybe the form was in another form? Like this `document.otherform.myform.od_proce`? Anyway, using document.getElementById or getElementsByName or querySelectorAll should be prefered since the suctrue can chage and these are more robust.

Comment: @Alxan: Besides, when you're doing more JavaScript coding in your webapp, you should checkout JavaScript frameworks, e.g. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), because they have their own ways when it comes to selecting elements.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the `name` of your form is `myform`:

```
<form name="myform" action="page.php" method="POST">
....
</form>
```

aslo add `name="od_price"` to :

```
<input id="od_price" name='od_price' .../>
```

Comment: it's already in form called "myform".

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `name` attribute on the `od_price` input. Add it to reference it correctly:

```html
<input id="od_price" name="od_price" type="text" size="4" value="<%=rs.fields.item("cust_price")%>" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();"  >
```

Comment: no.. it still produced the same error even though i added name="od_price" to that tag

Comment: was a long shot.. go with Tim Büthe's approach anyhow, as it's more semantic.